# Как закрыть окно ворда при сохранении через C#?

Tags: c#, com, ms-word, office

Прописал эту строку:

```
doc.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
```

документ закрывается, а окно приложения Word остаётся...
Как его закрыть?

Comment: Application.Quit();